# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/PostTest/home/segundaVista2]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsf-2

I am using InternalResourceViewResolver to resolve views and I having problems with methods using RequestMethod.POST when I try to execute an action from the view to the controller. I am getting the following error:

```
11:29:34,375 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/PostTest/home/segundaVista2] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

My controller is this:

```
@Controller("CatalogController")
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class CatalogControllerImpl implements CatalogController {

    private static final String GET_PRODUCTS_VIEW = "index";

    public CatalogControllerImpl() {
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getProducts(Map<String, Object> model) {

        System.out.println("Controller -> Getting products...");

        model.put("message", "Mensaje de prueba");

        System.out.println("Controller -> Finishing getting products...");

        return GET_PRODUCTS_VIEW;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="primeraVista", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String primeraVista() {
        return GET_PRODUCTS_VIEW;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="segundaVista", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String segundaVista() {
        return GET_PRODUCTS_VIEW + 2;
    }

}
```

And my view is this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Post test</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <form method="post" action="home/segundaVista2">
            <!--p:commandButton id="showMessage" value="showMessage" action="#{CatalogController.showMessage}" ajax="false" /-->
            Esta es la primera vista: <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your incoming URI is `segundaVista2`, but your `@RequestMapping` is just `segundaVista`.

Comment: Ok, I made that mistake trying to fix my action error. I will make another question related to this example. Thanks